# Two Imagebutton with same OnClick event.

Tags: c#, asp.net, imagebutton

I have two ImageButtons :

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="img1" runat="server" Width="50px" Height="50px" OnClick="CheckIMG" ImageUrl="../Icons/123.png" />
<asp:ImageButton ID="img2" runat="server" Width="50px" Height="50px" OnClick="CheckIMG" ImageUrl="../Icons/456.png" />
```

And the Method is :

```
protected void CheckIMG(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    HiddenField imgNameHF = (HiddenField)DetailsView1.FindControl("sent_info_to_db_HF");
    imgNameHF.Value = "'<%# CheckValue(Eval('" + img.ImageUrl + "')%>'";
}
```

How can i get on the line: `img.ImageUrl` of the `ImageButton` that the user cliked on ?

For Example:

- If `img1` clicked so the line will be: `img1.ImageUrl`
- If `img2` clicked so the line will be: `img2.ImageUrl`

Comment: Where is your ImageButton in DetailsView or out site ?

Comment: Out side the detailsview. only the hidenfield is on the DV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this.

```
protected void CheckIMG(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    HiddenField imgNameHF = (HiddenField)DetailsView1.FindControl("sent_info_to_db_HF");
    ImageButton imgb=(ImageButton) sender;
    imgNameHF.Value = "'<%# CheckValue(Eval('" + imgb.ImageUrl + "')%>'";
}
```

Comment: offcourse... thers 10 minuts past after the post for the mark as answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can Also Try this :

```
protected void CheckIMG(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    HiddenField imgNameHF = (HiddenField)DetailsView1.FindControl("sent_info_to_db_HF");
    ImageButton imgb = sender as ImageButton;
    imgNameHF.Value = "'<%# CheckValue(Eval('" + imgb.ImageUrl + "')%>'";
}
```